# What Type of Roof is This?

Tags: roof, layout, architecture

I'm trying to figure out what the name is for the roof structure my home has - it's a single level late 70s ranch, side-gabled, but the roof is broken up into multiple segments. Is there a name for a roof or general home layout of this type? I hope there are some architecture/design buffs on the site who can help out...

[image: unknown roof]

Comment: That is a combination of an open gable roof on the right and a skillion roof on the right and in the middle.  Of course there's no single term to describe this combination or every possible combination of roof types.

Comment: @batsplatsterson so the roof on the right has two different names?

Comment: Learned a new one, skillion, I only knew it to be a lean-to or shed roof. Here is my take on naming the roof configuration.... gable roof home and an addition with connecting hyphen with skillion roofs, or skillion roof home with skillion addition and gable roof combo, that is if the hyphen has a skillion roof

Comment: @SolarMike - my mistake, the ones on the LEFT and middle are skillion roofs.